# To run a batchupdate for every 10 values by iterating a map for 1000 rows

Tags: java, sql

In my application, I am getting(SELECT) around 1000 records from the DB and saving it in a map.
 Then I need to do a check and then UPDATE every 100 records(using batchupdate).
So there will be (10*100=1000) 10 set of the batchUpdates performed.
 If any set fails, we need to retry(re-loop) the set(of 100). The total records can be any number.
I tried the following. I just want to know if there are any better logic.

```
x=1000; //total records
y=100; //set of records that need to be updated
for(i=1 to y) {
  try{
  batchUpdate();
  } catch() {
    retry();
  }
if(i%y==0) { break;}

}
```

Can anyone please help me in getting any better logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use java jdbc batch update:

```
int x = 1000;//your total records
int y = 100;//set of records that need to be updated
String sql = "update xxx set xx = ?,yy=? ";
Connection dbConnection = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
try{
    dbConnection = getDBConnection(); //get your db connetion
    preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
    dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
    for(int i = 1;i < x;i++){
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, 101);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, "zzzz");
        preparedStatement.addBatch();
        if(i % y == 0){
            try{
                preparedStatement.executeBatch();// update y records
            }catch(Exception e){
                x -= 100;  //if failed ,roll back x 
            }
        }
    }
    preparedStatement.executeBatch(); // update rest of the reords
    dbConnection.commit();
}catch(Exception e){

}
```

wish can help you!